# Facebook API: a strange query error 601

Tags: facebook

I get this error while trying to obtain the number of shares and likes of the particular link on Facebook:

```
{
 "error_code":601,"error_msg":"
 Parser error: unexpected ''' at position 56.",
 "request_args":
          [{"key":"method","value":"fql.query"},
           {"key":"format","value":"json"},
           {"key":"query","value":"SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE
             url='http://www.lrinka.lt/index.php?act=main"},
           {"key":"item_id","value":"5963'"}]
}
```

The link: http://www.lrinka.lt/index.php?act=main&item_id=5963

The API call: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.lrinka.lt/index.php?act=main&item_id=5963%27

Everything works fine with other links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing the `url` parameter field correctly, missing `'` at the end of the URL.

Also no need for the "slashes", try the following in the [fql.query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) console:

```
SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http:\/\/www.lrinka.lt\/index.php?act=main
```

Would return the same error, and this:

```
SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http:\/\/www.lrinka.lt\/index.php?act=main'
```

Is valid but would return zero, and finally this:

```
SELECT share_count, like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http:\\www.lrinka.lt\index.php?act=main'
```

Would return the result expected.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment, you are trying to call `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY` with the `format` parameter set to `json`..so you need to encode the query, I used `encodeURI`:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='http:%5Cwww.lrinka.ltindex.php?act=main'
```

Comment: Actually, I am, but it's somehow not included in the error message. My API call: http://goo.gl/PUbA0 (with ' at the end)

Comment: @krn: still not included...have you tried the examples posted in my answer in the `fql.query` console?

Comment: Thanks for help, but I still don't get it. If you look at the address bar of my link - the ' is at the end of it. Just please at look the actual link which is used to call API when the page is open, because I even don't escape any quotes - the error doesn't say the truth.

Comment: @krn: Where should I look? the "goo.gl" links you posted are both missing the closing quote and both have slashes.

Comment: @krn: ahh, you are using json :-), just encode the `url` parameter..this should work: `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20share_count%2C%20like_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A%5Cwww.lrinka.ltindex.php%3Fact%3Dmain%27`